# Spring Integration: Framework Error Handling is Inconsistent

Tags: spring-integration

In my experience, the error handling strategy in various EIP components have little or no consistency.

**Case 1: handle**:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel)
    .enrichHeaders(spec -> spec.header(ERROR_CHANNEL, ARTIFACTORY_ERROR_CHANNEL, true))
    .handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(uri, webClient)
            .expectedResponseType(ArtifactSearchResponse.class)
            .httpMethod(GET)
            .mappedRequestHeaders(ACCEPT))
    .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, Message::getPayload)
    .handle(transformer)
    .channel(outputChannel)
    .get();
```

In this case, if `handle(transformer)` throws an exception, the message is sent to the `ARTIFACTORY_ERROR_CHANNEL` as expected, but the exception is returned to the caller. Thus, a test has to use `try-catch` to not fail.

```
try {
    inputChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("start"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // nop-op
}
verify(mockMessageHandler, timeout.times(1)).handleMessage(any(ErrorMessage.class));
```

**Case 2: transform**:
Change `handle(transformer)` to `transform(transformer)` and the exception is never sent to the `ARTIFACTORY_ERROR_CHANNEL` channel.

**Case 3: Gateway**:

```
public IntegrationFlow fileStreamingFlow() {
  return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel)
      .gateway(f -> f.handle(String.class, (fileName, headers) -> {
          throw new RuntimeException();
      }), spec -> spec.requiresReply(false).errorChannel(S3_ERROR_CHANNEL))
      .channel(outputChannel)
      .get();
  }
}
```

In this case, the calls blocks forever. See [#2451](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2451).

**Case 4: handle with routeByException**:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(s3Properties.getFileStreamingInputChannel())
    .enrichHeaders(spec -> spec.header(ERROR_CHANNEL, S3_ERROR_CHANNEL, true))
    .handle(String.class, (fileName, h) -> {
        return new ErrorMessage(new RuntimeException(), h);
    }, spec -> spec.requiresReply(false))
    .channel(outputChannel)
    .routeByException(r -> r.channelMapping(Exception.class, S3_ERROR_CHANNEL))
    .get();
}
```

In order for the exception to be sent to `S3_ERROR_CHANNEL`, I need to convert the exception to an `ErrorMessage`, and also apply a `routeByException` although there is already a previously configured `ERROR_CHANNEL`.

**What I expect**: If user defines an error channel, send all exceptions there. If the error handler associated to that channel returns `null`, terminate the flow; if it returns something else, continue. If user doesn't define an error channel, send the exception to the framework default error channel. Do this regardless of the flow definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. transformer - if your transformer returns `Message<?>`; it is responsible to propagate the `errorChannel` header.
3. When using a gateway, the error channel must be declared thereon rather than adding it later.
4. I don't understand what you are trying to do there.

In general, it's best to not manipulate framework headers in this way, but declare the channel on the proper elements (gateways, pollers etc).

Comment: 2. What if the transformer returns the payload only, and not `Message`? What if the call is made using `handle` instead of `transform`? 4. Trying to propagate the exception to the error channel using `handle` and conditional routing.

Comment: 2. Such a transformer will behave the same as any message handler.

Comment: It’s still not clear to me, since message handler signature doesn’t return anything, while transformer does. As for the gateway on my examples, it blocks waiting for a message from the error handler, which doesn’t return anything by the definition above. This is all very confusing; I think the docs warrant a section for “error handling”, with examples, because the only thing I found was a discussion on error channels.

Comment: I should correct my last response with "... as any reply-producing message handler` - most of which (including transformers) are subclasses of `AbstractReplyProducingMessagehandler`. If your error flow returns no reply, you should set an appropriate timeout on the gateway, perhaps even 0.

Comment: Now I’m beginning to understand. One (hopefully) last question: how are unhandled exceptions in `transform` and `handle` handles by the framework?

Comment: They are thrown to the caller (which might be a poller, in which case they are sent to the default `errorChannel`, unless the poller is configured with a specific error channel). You can also add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` (or a custom advice) to the endpoint's `adviceChain`. See [Adding behavior to endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

Comment: Ok, I lied about the last one being the last question. You recommended setting a timeout on the gateway, but it'll apply to the gateway in whole, right? For example, if my regular gateway flow takes 2 seconds, and my error handler returns nothing, setting a timeout of 0 on gateway would timeout the regular flow too. I don't see how to set a separate timeout for the error handler alone.

Comment: It's irrelevant if neither flow hands off work to another thread via a QueueChannel or ExectorChannel. The timer doesn't start until the thread returns to the gateway. 0 is perfect when only direct channels are  involved. Yes, if the main flow hands off to another thread then, yes, 0 would be a bad choice because the initial thread needs to wait for the reply. In that case, it would be better to have the error flow throw an exception back to the caller instead of returning nothing. A new timer is started for the error flow and again starts when the the thread returns.